# Nativescript-google-maps-sdk: mapView.zoom not changing zoom

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-google-maps-sdk

I am trying to change the zoom level after clicking on a marker. I've tried to redefine the zoom inside the onMarkerEvent() :

```
onMarkerEvent(args) {

    if (args.eventName === 'markerInfoWindowTapped') {
        this.routerExtenstions.navigate([`../item/${args.marker.userData.id}`], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });

    } else if (args.eventName === 'markerSelect') {
        this.zoom = 17;
        this.mapView.zoom = this.zoom;
    }
```

}

However, the zoom is not changing.

On map.component.tns.html I have:

```
   <MapView #mapView [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"
            [zoom]="zoom" [minZoom]="minZoom" [maxZoom]="maxZoom" [bearing]="bearing"
            [tilt]="tilt" i-padding="50,50,50,50" [padding]="padding" (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)"
            (markerSelect)="onMarkerEvent($event)" (markerInfoWindowTapped)="onMarkerEvent($event)" 
            (coordinateTapped)="onCoordinateTapped($event)"
            (cameraChanged)="onCameraChanged($event)" (mapAnimationsEnabled)="true"
            (cameraMove)="onCameraMove($event)">
    </MapView>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I feel that maybe be something basic I am forgetting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To adjust the zoom you might have better luck by changing the `mapView` properties directly, you can do so by accessing the `MapView` through the `args` inside of the `onMarkerEvent` function.

Doing `args.object.zoom = 17;` should do the trick.